# How do I disable auto rotation on iOS and Android?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I make it so that in Flutter, auto rotation does not do anything but only widgets on button press can change the orientation?

For example I use MediaQuery to check Orientation, and then give a particular widget based on that. However my widget button press is what changes the orientation, not the device sensor. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for my use case (though I would still like to know how to disable the sensor orientation changes and keep it manual):

I have a boolean for the widget button press, and I have the condition as such:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait && !isFullScreen
```

This will then disable any auto rotation and only rotate when my full screen button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the screen orientation in the configuration;

on ios platform:
[set iOS platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXk47.png)

on android platform:
[set android platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNMiu.png)